# How to process only on original image file using CarrierWave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I use CarrierWave to generate versions (thumbnails with different sizes) and also to add a watermark on each versions.

I have currently manage to apply the watermark for each thumbnails but I would like to add it on the original image to.

Here is what I tried:

```
def watermark
  manipulate! do |img|
    watermark   = Magick::Image.read(Rails.root.join('app/assets/images/watermark_512.png')).first
    img         = img.composite(watermark, Magick::CenterGravity, Magick::OverCompositeOp)
  end
end

version :original do
  process :watermark
end

version :thumb_512 do
  process :resize_to_fit => [512, 512]
  process :watermark
end

version :thumb_256 do
  process :resize_to_fit => [256, 256]
  process :watermark
end
```

But this does not work. However I tried to simply add

```
process :watermark
```

outside any "version" block but all it does is adding twice the watermark on my thumbnails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `store` callbacks provided by CarrierWave in your uploader class like this

```
class SomeUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  # Your code ...

  before :store, :watermark_method

  def watermark_method(*args)
    # watermark it!
  end
end
```

Comment: This is actually working ! But there is a small mistake. You need to pass the method's name as a symbol to "before", not the method itself. Maybe you could edit it :) Thank you anyway !

Comment: You are right, thanks for the noticing it, I wrote the code directly in SO, guess I was in a hurry :).