# How to place text on image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, imagemagick, minimagick

Is there a way to place text on image in Rails? I am using Carrierwave for image upload, but I don't think it supports watermarking.

I tried attaching image watermark and made it work but can't figure out how to watermark with text.

For example, [this](http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/196-how-to-add-a-watermark-to-pictures-with-minimagick-and-ruby) is good way to place image watermark.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13905516/612799

Answer (score 4):

This is the code that I user to put watermarks on a image I am sure that you can change it a bit to make it your own. Also make sure that you have `Magick` turned on.
Take a look at [carrierwave-add-a-watermark-to-processed-images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10619689/3659237) its similar

```
# Process files as they are uploaded:
process :resize_to_fill => [850, 315]
process :convert => 'png'
process :watermark

def watermark
  manipulate! do |img|
    logo = Magick::Image.read("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/watermark.png").first
    img = img.composite(logo, Magick::NorthWestGravity, 15, 0, Magick::OverCompositeOp)
  end
end
```

Comment: this answer is 4 years old. Can anyone give a updated syntex here? Thanks!